# Database design: How do I keep track of prepaid lessons aswell as paid after lessons?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

(Sorry for the bad title)

A student participates in lessons. Students are able to prepay for x-amount of lessons, i.e. a student can buy a five lesson package. My first question is, how do I keep track of when all of these lessons are "used up"?

A student can also book a lesson. When a student books a lesson the student will get a bill at the end of the month. How do I keep track of when a lesson has been paid or not?

My current solution looks like this:
[image]

It works by having a lesson entity with a "paid_on" column to keep track of when the lesson was paid for, this solves my second requirement (students can book lessons). However, how do I keep track of the prepaid lessons? The only solution I can come up with is adding a "number_of_prepaid_lessons" in the student entity that's either a fixed number, or decreases with every lesson created with their student_id. This doesn't feel like the optimal solution because it requires a lot of logic when a student for instance cancels a lesson (I don't want that lesson to be removed from their prepaid).

Comment: `mysql` or `postgresql` thats the question..... But which one are your really using ?   Use [edit] to remove the one that you are not using.

Comment: @Luuk sorry for the confusion

Comment: `"number_of_prepaid_lessons" in the student entity that's either a fixed number, or ...` Do not used a fixed number, because how would you deal with an extra prepay? and how would you keep track of the consumed part of the `number_of_prepaid_lessons`.  Simply decrease the value for every lesson that is payed (payed_on is filled with a value), and increase `number_of_prepaid_lessons` with 1 if the student cancels the lesson.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Luuk. However I want to avoid the logic of having to update the value of number_of_prepaid_lessons depending on the status of the lesson. Or is the best way just to update it accordingly? I'm new to SQL but I persume I would need some kind of function, or is it done "server-side" and not in the DBMS directly?

Comment: If you update the `number_of_prepaid_lessons`, and the `paid_on`, you should do this in one [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-transactions.html), to make sure both fields get updated, or no fields get updates.

Comment: Will this solution lead to negative `number_of_prepaid_lessons`?

Comment: This will, of course, only lead to negative numbers, if you do not check for `number_of_prepaid_lessons` to be larger than 1 before subtracting 1.

Comment: Can a student have (a) pre-paid XOR post-paid lessons, (b) pre-paid and/or post-paid lessons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a column named `enrollment_status` in `lessons` table and manage the lessons based on `booked`, `cancelled`, `ongoing/paid`. You will decide which `statuses` you want to count in and which ones not.

You can also bring another table called `package` and keep the `package_id` in `lessons` table to track which lessons are under some package. The `package` table may contain columns like `id`, `package_name`, `lesson_count`, `package_amount`, `valid_from`, `valid_to` etc.

You can take the count of the `lessons` for a particular `student` from `lessons` table by joining the `package` table on `package_id` for the specific package where the `lessons` have an valid `enrollment_status`. This search may also include the given date range in the search criteria which are in `between valid_from and valid_to` dates for the packages.

You can also keep track of the booked lessons only looking at the `enrollment_status` of the lessons taken by a specific student.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question. Does this mean that for the students that doesn't have a prepaid lesson, the foreign key column package_id will be null?

Comment: exactly, the `lessons` which are not taken under any `package`, will have `null` in the corresponding `package_id` column.

Comment: how would I go about adding a package to a student? Is that possible since we are storing the package_id reference in the lesson entity and not the student entity?

Comment: well, I haven't mentioned that in my answer as I thought the `student-package` relation is already kept(as that is a must soon after bringing the `package` table in the scene) and your `lesson` entity will have reference of both `student` and `package`.

Comment: @hampani, if it answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.